# Как выбрать записи которые >0, Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Как выбрать все колонки кроме пустых и значения которых больше нуля ?
Я делаю так :

```
query->exec("SELECT latitude,longitude,data FROM \"SchemeObservationLog\".data "
                        " WHERE id_log = "+QString::number(_IdLog)+" AND latitude IS NOT NULL AND latitude > 0 "
                        " AND latitude IS NOT NULL AND latitude > 0");
```

Но этот запрос выполняется с ошибкой.

Comment: И с какой ошибкой он выполняется, думаете мы телепаты и можем не видя структуры таблицы, по выглядящему корректно запросу, предсказать в чем проблема. P.S. проверки на is not null излишни. `>0` автоматом берет только not null

Comment: вот мне например кажется странным, что у вас части в кавычках на разных строках никакими операторами не объединяются. это какой язык, так позволяет ?

Comment: @Mike C++ язык. ошибка из-за latitude > 0 и latitude > 0. Не работает такое в Postgresql.

Comment: Этого не может быть. Числовые поля можно сравнивать на > 0, напишите точное сообщение об ошибке, которое возвращает postgress. Проверьте запрос в pgAdmin. Я вижу только две причины, почему проверка на больше может не работать: 1. В таблице нет поля latitude 2. Поле имеет какой то особый тип данных, который нельзя сравнивать с числами

Comment: @Mike Да вы правы у меня эти поля были строковыми.